# Take the average of numbers made with a dynamically created array

Tags: arrays, c, average

I basically have to make a program that takes input, allocates enough memory depending on that input, dynamically allocate the array of integers of that size, and find the average of those.
Example input:

```
Enter the number of integers: 5
0 1 2 3 4
average: 2
```

So far, with the code I have, I have done the first part but can't figure out how to find the average of the numbers I get from the input. I have read my notes and even googled for a solution similar to this but am getting nothing. This is the code I have so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    int* myData = NULL;
    int numData;
    int i;
    double average;

    printf("Enter the number of integers: ");

    scanf("%d", &numData);

    myData = (int*)malloc(numData * sizeof(int));


    for(i = 0; i < numData; ++i)
    {
      printf("%d ", i); 
              
        
    }

    printf("\n");
    
for(i = 0; i < numData; i++)
{
    average += myData[i];
}

printf("average: %lf", average);

   

    free(myData);

    return 0;

    


}
```

This is the output I get:

```
Enter the number of integers: 5
0 1 2 3 4 
average: 1215569347.000000
```

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: If you're really using dynamic allocation, just use it as pointer and not as array (`ptr++;` & `*ptr =...` etc.) . You are already dealing with pointers, why not go all in ? Its faster, but more importanty, IMO is actually easier to think of - just make sure you dont seg-fault :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to the uninitialized `average` and in addition to the fact you haven't filled `myData` with any data (leading to same problem adding indeterminate values to `average` each time), you leave yourself wide open to *Undefined Behavior* on the errant entry of a single non-digit key (like a user reaching for `'6'` but tapping `'t'` instead...)

You must validate EVERY user-input by ***checking the return*** for the input function used BEFORE using the value in your code ... and ... you must validate EVERY allocation before making use the pointer to the memory block. It's not a matter of **"if"** `malloc()` fails, it is a matter of **"when"** `malloc()` fails.

Additionally, you may want to provide more descriptive names in your code for intermediate steps. For example you are computing the `sum` not the average with:

```
average += myData[i];
```

The average computation comes later. An intermediate variable names `sum` would make that clear. (granted in short code it is readily apparent you are building the sum in `average` before dividing by `numData` to compute the final average -- but learning with good habits is much easier than breaking bad ones later)

Lastly since you are summing fairly large integer values in an integer type, it would make since to check for overflow in the addition before actually summing the numbers. A quick overflow test can be written by including `limits.h` for `INT_MAX` and `INT_MIN` and then:

```
#include <limits.h>

int addoverflow (int a, int b)
{
    if ((a > 0 && b > INT_MAX - a) ||
        (a < 0 && b < INT_MIN - a))
        return 1;
    
    return 0;
}
```

Which simply returns `1` if overflow would occur or `0` if not.

**Minimum Validation of User-Input**

To minimally validate user-input with `scanf`, you must check that the return is equal to the number of conversions requested (the conversion-count). For example for `numData`, you can do:

```
    printf("Enter the number of integers: ");

    if (scanf ("%d", &numData) != 1) {  /* validate EVERY user-input */
        fputs ("error: invalid integer input.\n", stderr);
        return 1;
    }
```

But since you will use `numData` as the *divisor* in computing `average`, you must make sure it is non-zero (and you cannot have a negative count), so non-negative as well. In other word, you must also validate the *range* of the user input to ensure it is valid. You can do that simply with:

```
    if (numData < 1) {  /* validate range of all inputs where needed */
        fputs ("error: input must be greater than 0.\n", stderr);
        return 1;
    }
```

(**note:** these are *minimum* validations. You ultimately want to handle errors in input gracefully, catching the error, clearing any offending characters from the input-buffer `stdin` and then giving the user an opportunity to correct -- but for now you must provide at least the minimum validations to avoid *Undefined Behavior* or *Floating Point Exceptions*)

**Validate Allocations**

As mentioned above, it isn't a matter of "if", but a matter of "when" `malloc` fails. Now with trivial examples there is little chance of failure, but that doesn't change your responsibility to validate your allocation succeeded. Again, you simply **check the return**. `malloc()` returns `NULL` on failure. You can do:

```
    /* validate EVERY allocation */
    if (!(myData = malloc(numData * sizeof *myData))) {
        perror ("malloc-myData");
        return 1;
    }
```

(**note:** In C, there is no need to cast the return of `malloc`, it is unnecessary. See: [Do I cast the result of malloc?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/995714). Further, it is recommended you use the dereferenced pointer to set type-size rather than the literal type. With fundamental types like `int` it is not usually a problem, but when allocating for an aggregate type, or for a pointer with several levels of indirection, it is easy to get wrong)

**Putting it Altogether**

Putting it altogether in a short example, including the use of a descriptive intermediate `sum`, you could do:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <limits.h>

int addoverflow (int a, int b)
{
    if ((a > 0 && b > INT_MAX - a) ||
        (a < 0 && b < INT_MIN - a))
        return 1;
    
    return 0;
}

int main(void)
{
    int *myData = NULL,
        numData,
        sum = 0;
    double average = 0;

    printf("Enter the number of integers: ");

    if (scanf ("%d", &numData) != 1) {  /* validate EVERY user-input */
        fputs ("error: invalid integer input.\n", stderr);
        return 1;
    }
    if (numData < 1) {  /* validate range of all inputs where needed */
        fputs ("error: input must be greater than 0.\n", stderr);
        return 1;
    }
    
    /* validate EVERY allocation */
    if (!(myData = malloc(numData * sizeof *myData))) {
        perror ("malloc-myData");
        return 1;
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < numData; ++i) {
        printf ("myData[%2d] : ", i);
        if (scanf ("%d", &myData[i]) != 1) {    /* validate! */
            fputs ("error: invalid integer input.\n", stderr);
            return 1;
        }
        if (addoverflow (sum, myData[i])) {     /* check overflow in addition */
            fputs ("error: overflow in addition.\n", stderr);
            return 1;
        }
        sum += myData[i];               /* now sum data */
    }
    average = (double)sum / numData;    /* take average */
    
    printf ("\nsum    : %d\naverage: %lf\n", sum, average);

    free(myData);       /* free allocated memory */
}
```

(**note:** there is no need to output a single `'\n'` with a separate call to `printf()`, and if a single `'\n'` was needed, the proper way to output a single-character is with `putchar()` instead)

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/avgdata
Enter the number of integers: 5
myData[ 0] : 13243360
myData[ 1] : 13243364
myData[ 2] : 13243368
myData[ 3] : 13243372
myData[ 4] : 13243376

sum    : 66216840
average: 13243368.000000
```

With intentional overflow:

```
$ ./bin/avgdata
Enter the number of integers: 5
myData[ 0] : 513243360
myData[ 1] : 513243364
myData[ 2] : 513243368
myData[ 3] : 513243372
myData[ 4] : 513243376
error: overflow in addition.
```

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions. Learning to handle errors in your code and avoid *Undefined Behavior* is equally important to getting the logic of your code correct. If either isn't handled correctly -- garbage output (or a segfault) may result.

Answer (score 1):

Your `average` was used without initialisation.

You need to initialise it first:

```
// double average;  // you do this and the initial value is a random value
double average = 0; // do this instead
```

Also you haven't entered any data of that `myData`.

```
for (i = 0; i < numData; ++i)
{
    // printf("%d ", i);     // instead of this
    scanf("%d", &myData[i]); // do this
}
```

And another bug on this line:

```
// printf("average: %lf", average);         // you forgot the divsion
printf("average: %lf", average / numData);  // do this instead
```

Comment: I tried all your suggestions and this is what I am getting instead:                                             Enter the number of integers: 5
13243360 13243364 13243368 13243372 13243376 
average: 992147034.200000

Comment: @Khoras pretty sure that you have not fixed all the errors I pointed out. I tried your data, and got: `Enter the number of integers: 5
13243360 13243364 13243368 13243372 13243376

average: 13243368.000000`